# Counting Chars in List<string> problems

Tags: c#-4.0

I looked, and maybe I'm not searching the right terms, but I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of chars in a List newList = List() in c#.

newList.Count only gives me the number of elements in the list. I can't find or figure out how to count the total number of chars in all elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to get the length of all of the strings in the array and sum them. It's very succinct.

```
var items = new List<string>
{
    "Hello",
    "World",
    "Foo",
    "bar",
    "Baz"
};

var totalLength = items.Sum(item => item.Length); // 19
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to loop through the List, and get the length of each individual string, adding them to a grand total.

```
        var names = new List<string>();
        names.Add("Sneezy");
        names.Add("Sleepy");
        names.Add("Dopey");
        names.Add("Doc");
        names.Add("Happy");
        names.Add("Bashful");
        names.Add("Grumpy");

        int totalLength = 0;
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            totalLength += name.Length;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(totalLength);
```